# How do I align text to any position I want to align it to?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is basically how I want my layout to look like:

[image]

There has to be a space separating the imageView from the Text. Ok button in the center, but I think the main challenge is making sure that the bold text is very closely aligned (almost touching the tip) to the regular text and is above it. Also, the added challenge is that all of this must be done using ONLY linear layout. So far, I have been using a vertical orientation linear layout followed by a horizontal orientation linear layout. The horizontal orientation linear layout covers the imageView and the regular text. My main problem is that I can not get the bold text and the regular text to align in the way I need it to.

By the way, I got rid of all the id's and images, since these are all private, but adding them should be no problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:text="Bold Text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Regular Text"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can't you drag and drop to achieve what you wish?

Comment: Why would you do it only using LinearLayouts?  That's not the right way to do this.  Stop wasting your time with pointless restrictions.

Comment: I know, that's the requirement I was given for this. @NegiBabu you can't drag and drop in linear layouts, but you can drag and drop in constraint and relative layouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless this is for a school project or something I wouldn't actually use nested layouts like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Bold Text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

Comment: No prob... glad it helped

Comment: if I can ask something else, how can I center the image to be in between the two textViews and within the space it is in? I do not want to "brute force it" using set 'dps' with marginLeft, marginRight, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't visualize what you're asking. Do you still want the image on the left of the two textviews, then centered vertically? Or textview - Image - textview so it's horizontal? Or something completely different

Comment: I want the imageView to still be in the left. I just want to push it down a bit. basically yes on the left of the two textviews, and then centered vertically.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure I understand what you're asking but I made an edit above. I'm assuming a pretty short image (10dp) then added android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" to the image properties.

Comment: Just tried that, and it worked perfectly! Thanks tgrable!

Answer (score 0):

Parent should be vertical linear layout, as you have now.

> > > First child should be horizontal linear layout
> > >
> > > > > > First child of that should be ImageView
> > > > > >
> > > > > > Second child should be BOLD TEXT with gravity=center_horizontal
> > >
> > > Second child of your parent should be Regular Text Blah Blah Blah with gravity=center_horizontal
> > >
> > > Third child of parent should be ok button with gravity=center_horizontal

If you want to add more space before things, give them android:marginStart="some_value"

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy_camera" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Bold Text"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="Regular Text"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to TextView parameters:

```
android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
```